# Dynamically created checkboxes elements are not call function assigned

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I have a set of checkboxes in Areas wrapper(div). When you checked one of them, the Linked Area wrapper will be show and then append itself to Linked Area wrapper. I want to remove a checkbox in Linked Area wrapper when I unchecked them, also uncheck the checkbox in area wrapper too.

I tried `on();` method but it's not working. It doesn't even call the on method.

I have a demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb5Gf/). Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.on`.

```
$(document).on("change",'#linked_areas_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]' ,function () {
```

#### **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb5Gf/5/)**

Comment: Sorry. I was try to accept it but it was too earlier. Now Accepted. :)